# Generating 3D TV stereoscopic output programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, 3d, television, stereoscopy

Do you know what would be the best approach to generate 3D output for one of these new "3D ready" televisions from software. Our application have some nice 3D visualizations, we want these to look nice.

Also, how feasible is it to generate it from a Flash (Flex) app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the gaming and 3DTV industries have paved the way for you.  As long as your app already outputs 3D visualizations, it may just be a matter of installing a driver.  You can get started with this [NVIDIA 3D Stereo User’s Guide](https://download.nvidia.com/Windows/77.77/77.77_3D_Stereo_User_Guide.pdf), but I believe there's tons of other stuff out there if you look.

See also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665688/is-stereoscopy-3d-stereo-making-a-come-back).

Comment: I imagined it was going to be like that, but info is a bit scarce about this subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

3D televisions can display 3D output only for images shot in 3D.  This means "intended for simulated 3D," not just a two-dimensional projection of a 3D image.

Stereoscopy is produced by generating two completely separate images per frame (one for each eye) in which the foreground objects are offset to simulate a 3D image.  You cannot take a 2D image and make it into a 3D image, the source frames must be produced as 3D frames from the beginning.

More information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_television

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy

Comment: We would like to show the 3D output in realtime using the 3DTV as a monitor. Can it be done programmatically? Or in otrher words, how do I tell the TV my output is "intended for simulated 3D"?